# How to get date and time of uploaded firmware?

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I have some kind of smart home on multiple esp8266, and I periodically update code of their firmwares via Arduino OTA. And sometimes I forget to upload actual code on them. For example, I don't remember, if I uploaded a new version of firmware to esp8266, that serves in toilet :) .

Each of Arduino esp8266 firmware is *.bin file, if I understood it correctly. Each of file has time of creation. And question is - does esp8266 store date and time of firmware, uploaded via OTA (or update) and is there any Arduino program method to get that date and time?

Comment: Instead of dealing with date/time, how about comparing cheksums, to check if the written code is up-to-date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Arduino typically does a full recomple you can use the macros `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` in your code where you would use a quoted string.

Eg, `client.println("Built " __DATE__)`

Or whatever you want to do with the information.

If the source file this appears in does not get rebuilt, it will not update, so in other environments you may need a custom build rule to force that.  Check stackoverflow where you will find many questions and answers on various forms of this.

It can be useful to capture the git hash and clean/dirty state, too.

Comment: its a good idea to add some command / pragma for the linker, so information like versioning (version, builddate, compiler version, string which states about a certain modification,etc... ) is placed at an static address. So it can be read easyly by the µC and on the PC as well

Comment: Thank you very much!